# get json object from stringify object using jq filter in shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

i am wring the shell script as i am new. my query is 
i have json object like

```
{
   "logo": {"name":"logo.png","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php8B97.tmp","error":0,"size":110290},
   "template":"template1",
   "firstname":"a",
   "lastname":"a",
   "username":"a",
   "password":"aa",
   "email":"a",
   "categoriesListArr":"{\"Women\":[\"All footwear\",\"All footwear\",\"All Clothing\",\"All Clothing\",\"All Watches\",\"All Watches\",\"All Sunglasses\",\"All Sunglasses\"],\"Men\":[\"All Mens Accessories\",\"All Bags,Belts And wallets\",\"All Fragrances\",\"All Grooming and wellness\"]}",
   "aboutUs":"aa",
   "contactUs":"78787878878787",
   "deliveryInfo":"aa",
   "privacyPolicy":"aa",
   "t&d":"aa"
}
```

i extracted the categoriesListArr using jq filter as follows:

```
categories=`cat detail.json| jq '.categoriesListArr'`
```

detail.json is the name of the file.
now categories is stringify object...i need to parse it and convert it into json object.

```
"{\"Women\":[\"All footwear\",\"All footwear\",\"All Clothing\",\"All Clothing\",\"All Watches\",\"All Watches\",\"All Sunglasses\",\"All Sunglasses\"],\"Men\":[\"All Mens Accessories\",\"All Bags,Belts And wallets\",\"All Fragrances\",\"All Grooming and wellness\"]}"
```

how i can convert it using jq filter

Comment: so are you writing `javascript`, `shell` or `php`?

Comment: shell..as i have mentioned above

Comment: but not as you had tagged :)

Comment: The first part is easy: `jq '.categoriesListArr' detail.json`. I'm not sure how to "decode" the string after, though.

Comment: yes the first part is done..what about the second part..how to convert stringify object  to json

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*fromjson* is your friend:

```
$ jq '.categoriesListArr | fromjson' detail.json
```

Or, if you want to retain the original structure:

```
$ jq '.categoriesListArr |= fromjson' detail.json
```

Comment: FYI fromjson was added in version 1.4.